# Менеджер вкладок (Осторожно г*внокод)

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте!

Насколько костыльно я сделал менеджер вкладок?

Хотелось бы услышать какие-то комментарии и желательно советы по улучшению, только учусь JavaScript'у.

Разметку и верстку прикладываю.

Верстка: http://smart-kids-shop.ru/dd/

HTML:

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="denis">ДЕНИС</a></li>
                        <li><a class="anya">АНЯ</a></li>
                        <li><a class="artem">АРТЕМ</a></li>
                        <li><a class="yulia">ЮЛЯ</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div id="denis">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Персональный тренер - Денис</h2>
                <hr align="left">
                <p>« Регулярные тренировки и правильное питание -
                    залог здоровья и красоты! ЕМS-тренировки - это
                    инновация в сфере фитнеса. Отличное решение для создания
                    фигуры мечты и укрепления здоровья.
                    Моя цель - привести клиента к желаемому результату »</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="anya">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>Персональный тренер - Аня</h2>
                <hr align="left">
                <p> Тренер Аня <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
                    различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
                    обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
                    административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
                    что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
                    реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
                    кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="artem">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Персональный тренер - Артем</h2>
            <hr align="left">
            <p> Тренер Артем <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
                различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
                обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
                административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
                что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
                реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
                кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="yulia">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Персональный тренер - Юля</h2>
            <hr align="left">
            <p> Тренер Юля <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
                различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
                обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
                административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
                что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
                реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
                кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function () {
    $('a.denis').addClass( "active" );
    $('#anya').hide();
    $('#artem').hide();
    $('#yulia').hide();
})

$('a.anya').click(function () {
    $('#denis').hide();
    $('#yulia').hide();
    $('#artem').hide();
    $('a.denis').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.yulia').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.artem').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.anya').addClass( "active" );
    $('#anya').show();
})

$('a.denis').click(function () {
    $('#anya').hide();
    $('#yulia').hide();
    $('#artem').hide();
    $('a.anya').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.yulia').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.artem').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.denis').addClass( "active" );
    $('#denis').show();
})

$('a.artem').click(function () {
    $('#anya').hide();
    $('#yulia').hide();
    $('#denis').hide();
    $('a.anya').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.yulia').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.denis').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.artem').addClass( "active" );
    $('#artem').show();
})

$('a.yulia').click(function () {
    $('#anya').hide();
    $('#artem').hide();
    $('#denis').hide();
    $('a.anya').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.artem').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.denis').removeClass( "active" );
    $('a.yulia').addClass( "active" );
    $('#yulia').show();
})
```

Внимание на этот блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень уж "костыльно". Насколько знаю, у бутстрапа есть свое решение для вкладок - почему бы не воспользоваться им?

Comment: bootstrap по дефолту имеет свои табы https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: @soledar10, а класс active сам присваивается в bootstrap'е? (В табах)

Comment: присваивается attr - [aria-expanded="true"]. + добавить класс нет никакой сложности

Comment: @Cheg, а чем плохо такое решение?

Comment: @user234223 абсолютно неуниверсальное, под каждые ссылку+блок нужно добавлять код

Comment: пример без bootstrap - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/8rh72gsw/

Comment: вы не находите, что в принципе ваш js-код повторяется несколько раз?

Comment: @teran, он повторяется. Переменные разные.

Comment: @teran выше я дал знать что если будут идеи касающиеся его сокращения или улучшения, будет просто здорово

Comment: дак я и написал "в принципе", а не "в точности"

Comment: @teran критикуете, предлагайте))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из ваших задач как разработчика, писать код, который в том числе можно использовать повторно и уницифировать. Очень наглядная задача в этом смысле - реализация калькулятора. Вы же не будете для нажатия каждой кнопки писать свой обработчик? Следует написать один, но универсальный, так как действие - типовое.

Покуда вам не требуется создавать анимации при запуске страницы - выставляйте классы для отображения/скрытия элементов изначально при построении html на стороне сервера. Нет смысла делать то же самое в скрипте при старте.

Как вам уже написали в комментариях, все что вы пытались реализовать уже есть в стандартном бутстрапе. Но, если оставить его в стороне, то ваше решение для скрытия блоков при нажатии на ссылки должно иметь следующий вид. В таком варианте оно достаточно кратко и расширяемо при добавлении новых вкладок.

```js
$(".person-tabs a.tab").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".person-tabs a, .person-info").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass('active');  
      
   $(".person-info#"+$(this).data('info-id')).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.person-info { display: none; }
.person-info.active { display: block; }
a.tab.active { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="person-tabs">
        <li><a class="tab active" data-info-id="denis">ДЕНИС</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" data-info-id="anya">АНЯ</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" data-info-id="artem">АРТЕМ</a></li>
        <li><a class="tab" data-info-id="yulia">ЮЛЯ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="denis" class="person-info active">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Персональный тренер - Денис</h2>
            <hr align="left">
            <p>« Регулярные тренировки и правильное питание -
                залог здоровья и красоты! ЕМS-тренировки - это
                инновация в сфере фитнеса. Отличное решение для создания
                фигуры мечты и укрепления здоровья.
                Моя цель - привести клиента к желаемому результату »</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

      <div id="anya" class="person-info">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <h2>Персональный тренер - Аня</h2>
              <hr align="left">
              <p> Тренер Аня <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
                  различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
                  обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
                  административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
                  что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
                  реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
                  кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
          </div>
      </div>

  <div id="artem" class="person-info">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Персональный тренер - Артем</h2>
          <hr align="left">
          <p> Тренер Артем <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
              различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
              обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
              административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
              что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
              реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
              кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="yulia" class="person-info">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <h2>Персональный тренер - Юля</h2>
          <hr align="left">
          <p> Тренер Юля <br> Таким образом дальнейшее развитие
              различных форм деятельности в значительной степени
              обуславливает создание существенных финансовых и
              административных условий. Повседневная практика показывает,
              что сложившаяся структура организации способствует подготовки и
              реализации форм развития. Таким образом рамки и место обучения
              кадров влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <img class="trainer" src="img/denis.png" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```